# Python IF statement without comparison operators

Tags: python

I know people on SO/SE are a bit butthurt that no one knows where to asks the questions, so I hope this thread somehow fits into this sub forum ;-)

If i have to check if a value in my django model is set (!= None) i do it like this:

```
if not model.fiel:
    model.field = some_logic()
```

It feels pretty pythonic but i honestly don't know that this if statement does. I assume it check if the Value is True/False? If the Value is 0 or an empty iterable ('', {}, () or []) it will also fail.

I find my self using this alot because its pretty convenient. Could someone explain to me what it does or why i shouldn't (or should) use it?

Edit (add example):

```
#imports
from apptime.models import Incident
from django.utils import timezone
import requests

#part of logic
#django queryset (list like object filled with DB models
incidents = Incident.object.filter(monitor=client)
#check if queryset is not empty;
if incidents:
    #get latest
    incident = incidents.latest('start_downtime')
    #check if fk model has datetime field set
    if not incident.monitor.down_since:
        #set datetime field if not jet set
        incident.monitor.down_since = timezone.now()
```

I think that the `if` call to a variable calls the `bool()` built-in function. At least it acts exactly like it, so I'll just continue to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a bit hard to review code like this because the code you are showing is example code rather than code that you're actually using in a real project, which means that a lot of context has been stripped away. Unlike Stack Overflow, we prefer to look at real code instead of example code. Please see the meta question: [Why is hypothetical code off-topic for Code Review?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/41243)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I added an example to show what i mean in real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `if not model.fiel` does depending on its type, usually for built-in types a falsy value is one of the following:

- `None`
- `False`
- zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
- any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
- any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.

If it is a user-defined type then Python looks for methods like [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__)  ([`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) in Python 3) and [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__), if they return 0 or boolean `False` then it is falsy otherwise `True`. Note that from `__nonzero__` we can only return a bool type and from `__len__` we can return both bool as well as an integer.

Apart from this everything else is considered `True` in Python.

Coming back to what you asked: If you want to check whether the field is not `None` then better use the the `is` operator as `None` is a singleton. Using simple `if not model.fiel` will fail for the all the falsy values mentioned above including `None`. Note that `is` checks for identity rather than falsyness, as we mostly use `None` wherever we don't have any data, we cannot use a simple `if` because `0`, `[]`, `''`, etc are not considered as missing data in most cases.

From [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is` or
>   `is not` , never the equality operators.

```
if model.fiel is not None:
    model.field = some_logic()
```

Comment: I did know that singletons should be compared with `is` and not `==` and big numbers the other way around (i found out the hard way) But if i want to check if a field is set or still None, what whould be the difference between `if value:` and `if value is None:`.
The advantage that I get from `if value:` is that None and an empty list will fail the if statement

Comment: @YannikAmmann I already explained what `if value` will do, and with `if value is None` we are telling Python to explicitly check it against None rather than any falsy value. Note that `is` checks for identity, means  it checks whether a particular name is just another reference to an object.

Comment: @YannikAmmann You shouldn't compare any type of number using `is`, always use `==` for numbers. `is` works for small number only because CPython caches them, it's not a language rule just a CPython thing.

Comment: Ok i think i've understood this now. If you use `IF` on a value it checks if the value somehow represents False and if you use `IS` you check if the value is a representation and `==` to check if they both have the same value. Thanks for the clarification.